# Custom ResourceProviderFactory Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, resourceproviderfactory

Is there anywhere in ASP.NET MVC where you can get a reference to the ResourceProviderFactory that is instantiated in order to perform Property Injection to add a custom DB Implementation to retrieve the resources from?

I have a custom resource provider being loaded but I wanted to know whether there was an alternative to using a Static DI container to inject the dependency within the Provider.

Similar to how you can inject for the Role and Membership providers in MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to implement an infrastructure component calls into MVC's `DependencyResolver.Current`, so you can register the real `ResourceProviderFactory` using your favorite DI container.

Here is such a class that will do the trick:

```cs
public class MvcResourceProviderFactory : ResourceProviderFactory
{
    public override IResourceProvider CreateGlobalResourceProvider(
        string classKey)
    {
        return GetFactory().CreateGlobalResourceProvider(classKey);
    }

    public override IResourceProvider CreateLocalResourceProvider(
        string virtualPath)
    {
        return GetFactory().CreateLocalResourceProvider(virtualPath);
    }

    private static ResourceProviderFactory GetFactory()
    {
        var resolver = DependencyResolver.Current;

        var factory = resolver.GetService<ResourceProviderFactory>();

        if (factory != null)
        {
            return factory;
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
            "No {0} has been registered in the {1}.",
            typeof(ResourceProviderFactory).FullName,
            DependencyResolver.Current.GetType().FullName));
    }
}
```

This class can be configured as follows:

```xml
<globalization
    resourceProviderFactoryType="MyApp.MvcResourceProviderFactory, MyApp"
    enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"
/>
```

Comment: I gave you the correct answer on this as it answers the question. I was aware of the this method of implementing what I was looking for but I was more interested in if there was an alternative method to handling the dependency injection instead of using the above which I am currently using.

Comment: I have been struggling with this for a while and best approach I have found, good or bad...