# Poor DependencyInjection CustomMembershipProvider possibilities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-membership

Trying to inject a repository into my `CustomMembershipProvider`.

Let me start that I am **not** in fond of the **`Singleton` pattern** or some other *global public* solutions.

Here is a sample of the `CustomMemberhipProvider`

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : BaseMembershipProvider
{
    private readonly UserRepository _userRepository;

    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        // Magically pull the userrepository in here?
        base.Initialize(name, config);
    }
}
```

The only working example I found so far is to add a `Factory`, which is yet-another-alternative for some `global public` class.

- Is there nothing out there that allows me properly inject an object (`UserRepository`) to the `CustomMembershipProvider`?
- If not, is there a good alternative? I am not married to the CustomMembershipProvider, so if there is something else out there that allows me to use `[Authorize]` attributes in my controller, then I'm all for it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Related: [Custom ResourceProviderFactory Dependency Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619962/custom-resourceproviderfactory-dependency-injection)

Comment: So the best you can get here is some kind of global public repository provider?

Comment: In MVC there already is an global public provider, it is called `DependencyResolver.Current`. It's not advisable to call it from within your application logic (since this makes testing harder), but it's okay to call it from within some piece of MVC infrastructure logic. My advice: Create your `MvcMembershipProvider` just like the `MvcResourceProviderFactory` and call `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(MembershipProvider))` to resolve the real provider. Or use the Griffin framework as referenced in the duplicate question.

Comment: Another solution is to write your own AuthorizeAttribute, like http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes . You can use dependency injection for asp.net action filters so I think that you can use it also for authorize attribute.

Comment: Cool, bookmarked that. Thanks for the help!