# ResourceProviderFactory - Using Castle.Windsor to inject IResourceProvider

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

New to dependency injection and using IoCs but on my latest ASP.NET MVC 3 project we've gone with Castle.Windsor.

We're implementing a custom ResourceProviderFactory and wanted to inject the IResourceProvider and it's dependencies. So we exposed the container via the IContainerAccessor in the global.asax and explicitly Resolve:

```
    public class DynamicResourceProviderFactory : ResourceProviderFactory
    {
        protected virtual IResourceProvider GetResourceProvider(string resourceName)
        {
            IContainerAccessor accessor = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance as IContainerAccessor;            
            return accessor.Container.Resolve<IResourceProvider>(new Arguments(new { resourceName = resourceName }));
        }

        public override IResourceProvider CreateGlobalResourceProvider(string resourceName)
        {
            return GetResourceProvider(resourceName);
        }
    }
```

I was reading the Windsor docs about Typed Factories -

> Use typed factories wherever you need to pull something from the
>   container.

Is a typed factory the better way to get an IResourceProvider from the container?

Comment: Want to give your question a better, more meaningful title?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom ResourceProviderFactory Dependency Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619962/custom-resourceproviderfactory-dependency-injection)