# Castle.Windsor - understanding transient lifestyle

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, lifecycle

New to Castle.Windsor and just wanted to check something.

I've been reading about transient lifestyles and "releasing what you resolve" - I've created a Resource provider for my ASP.NET MVC3 application and am resolving it within my new resource provider factory (which is the "hub" for resource access in ASP.NET):

```
IContainerAccessor accessor = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance as IContainerAccessor;            
IResourceProvider provider = accessor.Container.Resolve<IResourceProvider>(new Arguments(new { resourceName = resourceName }));

LoggerService.Information(String.Format("Tracking? {0}", accessor.Container.Kernel.ReleasePolicy.HasTrack(provider)));
```

The `IResourceProvider` is transient so I can pass a different `resourceName` to the constructor (so different labels can be returned from different resource files).

I was concerned I'd need to explicitly call `Release` on these `IResourceProvider` objects but my `HasTrack` check always returns `false` - so I assume this is a good thing?

The container isn't tracking this object so the GC will (eventually clean this object up).

When then would the container track this object - if it had creation commission concerns?

Answer (score 3):

You only release components that you explicity ask for.
There are 2 ways of explicitly obtaining a component:

a) Resolve, which you used above. In general it is a good practise to only have a single resolve call in your application. So you probably want to look into the TypedFactoryFacility.

b) Use of a factory. In this case you would use the TypeFactoryFacility. If you obtain a component from a factory it and it's dependencies will be released when:

- You release it explicitly by calling a "destroy" method on your factory.
- Or the factory it self is released.

If you didn't create a component explicitly you should never have to release it.

Comment: Thanks Marwijn, but I've explicitly asked for my IResourceProvider in the example code - yet its not being tracked (I thought it would be because I'd resolved). If I used a Typed Factory I'd still need to resolve the factory so I'm not hiding the container that way (which I understood was the benefit to factories?). But I think I see your point, by using the factory the IResourceProvider created is owned by the factory and will be released when it is. When is a Typed Factory released then?

Comment: Hello Neil, with the limited information I have I can't really judge on whether you should use a factory or not. I just wanted to point out to you that having multiple Resolves in your application is kind of an anti-pattern. You are right that the container has no reason to track your component since you have no decomission requirements. However be aware that adding a dependency to the resource provider that does have one (like IDisposable) will be enough to have it tracked. My advice would be to be on the save site and release when you are done.

Comment: Thanks Marwijn - really appreciate your comments. I think the fact that ASP.NET doensn't provide a clean hook to inject this kind of resource factory isnt helping. Essentially I'm trying to do a Windsor version of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619962/custom-resourceproviderfactory-dependency-injection but avoiding the service locator style is possible.

Comment: Maybe the wcf facility can help you: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.WCF-Integration-Facility.ashx