# How do I control the lifetime of a custom IResourceProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, castle-windsor, resourceproviderfactory

I've taken [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619962/custom-resourceproviderfactory-dependency-injection) to injecting a custom resource provider in my ASP.NET MVC application, but I'm having some problems with object lifetime management.

I'm using Castle Windsor, so I have the following implementation of the factory:

```
public class DefaultResourceProviderFactory : ResourceProviderFactory
{
    public override IResourceProvider CreateGlobalResourceProvider(string classKey)
    {
        // IoC is a static helper class that gives me static access to the
        // container. IoC.Resolve<T>(args...) simply calls container.Resolve<T>(args...).
        return IoC.Resolve<IResourceProvider>(new { resourceType = "Global" });
    }

    public override IResourceProvider CreateLocalResourceProvider(string virtualPath)
    {
        // resourceType
        return IoC.Resolve<IResourceProvider>(new { ResourceType = virtualPath });
    }
}
```

However, the `IResourceProvider` I have registered in the container doesn't seem to have its lifetime managed correctly. It has some other dependencies of its own, some of which have somewhat complicated lifestyles (per web request or per transaction), so I've registered the `IResourceProvider` as transient to ensure that its dependencies are always valid. But the MVC framework is stepping on my toes, keeping a reference to the `IResourceProvider` across web requests, which causes `ObjectDisposedExceptions` when its dependencies have been invalidated on the next request.

What I'd like to do, is to make the MVC framework use the factory *every time* it needs an instance of my `IResourceProvider`, and - if possible - also to invoke `IoC.Release(provider)` or something similar when it's done with it.

How do I micro-manage the lifestyle of the custom `IResourceProvider` in a way that the MVC framework will respect?

Comment: You might need to handle type resolving manually inside your custom IResourceProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around for various ways to control the lifetime of the `IResourceProvider` itself, I decided that it was better to refactor my implementation to utilize the [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories).

My `IResourceProvider` implementation formerly looked something like this:

```
public class CachedResourceProvider : IResourceProvider {
    CachedResourceProvider(IResourceRecordRepository repo) { /* ... */ }
    // other members...
}
```

Now, I changed it to this instead:

```
public class CachedResourceProvider : IResourceProvider {
    CachedResourceProvider(IResourceRecordRepositoryFactory repo) { /* ... */ }
    // other members...
}
```

The factory interface is a new one, defined as

```
public interface IResourceRecordRepositoryFactory {
    IResourceRecord NewInstance();
    void Release(IResourceRecord instance);
}
```

and every usage of the private `_repo` instance in the `CachedResourceProvider` was refactored to three statements: get a repo instance from the factory, use the repo instance to fetch/save something, release the instance through the factory.

I registered them like this:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(Component.For<IResourceRecordRepositoryFactory>().AsFactory());
```

Now, even though MVC is keeping a reference to my resource provider across web requests, the services it uses are re-fetched from the Windsor container each time they're used, so the container is in full control of their lifetime.